# spark unable to save in hadoop (permission denied for user)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I build a spark application to count the number of word in a file. I run the application on the cloudera quickstart VM, all is fine when i use the cloudera user directory but when i want to write or read in an other user directory i have a permission denied from hadoop. I would like to know how to change the hadoop user in spark.

```
package user1.item1

import user1.{Article}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Context.User = 'espacechange'
    val filename = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/user1/test/wiki_test/wikipedia.txt"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("word count")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val wikipedia = sc.textFile(filename).map(Article.parseWikipediaArticle)
    val counts = wikipedia.flatMap(line => line.text.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

    counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/user1/test/word_count")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to launch the spark-submit script using a different OS user.

For example, use the following command to run the spark application as (and get the permissions of) the HDFS user:

```
sudo -u hdfs spark-submit ....
```

Comment: This work but i don't like it. I would have preferred something added in the code or in the submission argument.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your cluster's authentication. By default, you can set following environment variable:

```
$ export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
```

Try the above before submitting spark job.